# Angular2 route-link from child component has no effect

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I was experimenting with Angular2's router (2.0 beta 6), I encountered an issue regarding a `routeLink` (or `router.navigate`) being called from a child component.

My main component looks like this:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'myapp',
  template:`
  <div>
    <alink></alink>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ALinkComponent],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
      path: '/first',
      name: 'First',
      component: FirstComponent,
      useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
      path: '/second',
      name: 'Second',
      component: SecondComponent
    }
])
export class MyApp {
}
```

`<alink>` simply shows a link with a `[routerLink]` to `Second`:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'alink',
  template: `<h3><a [routerLink]="['Second']">Should redirect to second</a></h3>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class ALinkComponent {
}
```

However, when clicking on this link, nothing happens (not even a message pops up on the console). A link from the `MyApp` template works perfectly find. Using a `(click)=...` handler with `router.navigate(...)` also doesn't work.

What do I need to change in order to make the `routerLink` work in any nested component?

A full example is available [on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RBCwdkHtVFhXBu60jEd6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your example working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/haZLsy0wR3MTFNKKZ4ie?p=preview), but I had to add a fair amount of code. The problem is that `ALinkComponent` doesn't have a `RouteConfig` of its own, so it needs to access `MyApp`'s router and call its `navigate` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! Your idea of injecting the parent and using its router actually brought me on the right path. I just found another way which seems easier to me but migh have disadvantages under some circumstances: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35369679/2597135

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@MattScarpino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354479/2597135) very helpful answer and [this blogpost](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/) I was able to figure out a more simple way of doing this without injecting `MyApp` directly:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'alink',
  template: `<h3><a (click)="viewSecond()">Should redirect to second but does not</a></h3>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class ALinkComponent {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.router = injector.parent.get(Router);
  }

  viewSecond() {
    this.router.navigate(["Second"])
  }
}
```

The disadvantage of this solution is likely that we might need to use `parent` or `parent.parent` depending on the circumstances. However, we avoid explicit references to the toplevel component.